# How do I label my figure properly?

Tags: floats, labels

I have my figure as a pdf with commands:

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering\includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth] {babymodel_figure_4.pdf}
\caption{The Fixed-Point Equation }
\end{figure}
```

These are my packages:

```
\documentclass[11pt,reqno]{amsart}

% Packages
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibpunct{(}{)}{;}{;}{,}{,}
\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage[
  colorlinks=true,
  citecolor=blue,
  urlcolor=blue,
  linkcolor=blue
]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{ amssymb }


\pagestyle{plain}

\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}
\setlength{\parindent}{12pt}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}

\allowdisplaybreaks[4]

% Commenting/debugging
\let\IG\iffalse
\let\ENDIG\fi

%% Shortcuts
\newcommand{\td}[2]{\dfrac{d #1}{d #2}}
\newcommand{\std}[2]{\dfrac{d^2 #1}{d {#2}^2}}
\newcommand{\ctd}[3]{\dfrac{d^2 #1}{d #2 d #3}}

\newcommand{\pd}[2]{\dfrac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}
\newcommand{\spd}[2]{\dfrac{\partial^2 #1}{\partial {#2}^2}}
\newcommand{\cpd}[3]{\dfrac{\partial^2 #1}{\partial #2 \partial #3}}

\newcommand{\pdi}[2]{\partial #1/\partial #2}

\newcommand{\LR}{\Leftrightarrow}
\newcommand{\Lg}{\mathcal{L}}
\newcommand{\half}{\tfrac{1}{2}}
\newcommand{\eqp}{\phantom{=}}
\newcommand{\eqs}{\buildrel s \over =}
```

Here is what I'm getting in the pdf: [image]

I want it like this "Figure 1: Fixed-Point Equation"

Thanks

Comment: So you just want to have a colon instead of a period? `Figure 1:` instead of `Figure 1.`?

Comment: `\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelfont=normalfont,labelsep=colon}`

Comment: @HarishKumar: You were quicker again ... :D

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Go ahead if you want to answer. Use my comment above and cook up a mwe. :-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Yeah, pretty much.

Comment: @user36829 Then you won't need `labelfont=normalfont`

Comment: Without `caption`: `\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\def\@captionheadfont{\normalfont}   %% originally \scshape
\xpatchcmd{\@makecaption}{.\@captionfont\upshape\enspace}{:\@captionfont\upshape\enspace}{}{}
\makeatother`

Comment: @HarishKumar: No, it's to easy...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [caption](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption) package provides the `\captionsetup` macro to modify a great many aspects of the output of the `\caption` macro (and, just for completeness, of the `\captionof` macro). The following code illustrates how to modify two such aspects: the font that's used for the label, and the separator between the label and the captioning text itself. (I've commented out all instructions from your preamble that aren't relevant for the matter at hand.)

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,reqno]{amsart}
% Packages
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}  % omit "demo" option in real document
%\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm}
%\usepackage{natbib}
%\bibpunct{(}{)}{;}{;}{,}{,}
%\usepackage{xr-hyper}
%\usepackage[
%  colorlinks=true,
%%%  citecolor=blue,
%%%  urlcolor=blue,
%%%  linkcolor=blue
%  allcolors = blue
%]{hyperref}
%\usepackage{bm}
%\usepackage{fullpage}
%%%\usepackage{ amssymb }  % duplicate
%
%
%\pagestyle{plain}
%
%\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}
%\setlength{\parindent}{12pt}
%
%\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}
%
%\allowdisplaybreaks[4]
%
%% Commenting/debugging
%\let\IG\iffalse
%\let\ENDIG\fi
%
%%% Shortcuts
%\newcommand{\td}[2]{\dfrac{d #1}{d #2}}
%\newcommand{\std}[2]{\dfrac{d^2 #1}{d {#2}^2}}
%\newcommand{\ctd}[3]{\dfrac{d^2 #1}{d #2 d #3}}
%
%\newcommand{\pd}[2]{\dfrac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}
%\newcommand{\spd}[2]{\dfrac{\partial^2 #1}{\partial {#2}^2}}
%\newcommand{\cpd}[3]{\dfrac{\partial^2 #1}{\partial #2 \partial #3}}
%
%\newcommand{\pdi}[2]{\partial #1/\partial #2}
%
%\newcommand{\LR}{\Leftrightarrow}
%\newcommand{\Lg}{\mathcal{L}}
%\newcommand{\half}{\tfrac{1}{2}}
%\newcommand{\eqp}{\phantom{=}}
%\newcommand{\eqs}{\buildrel s \over =}

\begin{document}

without an explicit \verb+\captionsetup+ instruction:
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering\includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth] {babymodel_figure_4.pdf}
\caption{The Fixed-Point Equation }
\end{figure}

\captionsetup{labelsep=colon}
with \verb+\captionsetup{labelsep=colon}+:
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering\includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth] {babymodel_figure_4.pdf}
\caption{The Fixed-Point Equation }
\end{figure}

\captionsetup{labelsep=colon,labelfont=normalfont}
with \verb+\captionsetup{labelsep=colon,labelfont=normalfont}+:
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering\includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth] {babymodel_figure_4.pdf}
\caption{The Fixed-Point Equation }
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```